# Why won't Git add/commit files when node_modules folder isn't ignored in .gitignore?

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, node-modules

### The question

I can't add or commit with git when node_modules isn't ignored in the .gitignore file. When it is, everything works just fine.

Why is this? I do not understand and it bugs me. Is it ok not to upload the node_modules folder? I push and deploy to Amazon Web Services with their eb cli tool.

### Details

I'm new to web devolopment. I use laravel 5 with homestead, and currently try to move my app from heroku to Amazon Web Services.

When my .gitignore look like this:

```
/vendor
.env


# Elastic Beanstalk Files

.elasticbeanstalk/*

!.elasticbeanstalk/*.cfg.yml

!.elasticbeanstalk/*.global.yml
```

It says "no changes added to commit" when I run

`git add -A`

and then

`git commit -m "Test Message"`

but there is. I added a test change to my about file.

But then if I ignore the node_modules folder like this:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
.env


# Elastic Beanstalk Files

.elasticbeanstalk/*

!.elasticbeanstalk/*.cfg.yml

!.elasticbeanstalk/*.global.yml
```

and add and commit again, the change is registered as it should.

Comment: Is there another .gitignore file within the /node_modules folder?

Comment: it has 3 files. .bin, gulp and laravel-elixir. If I search for .gitignore, it finds .gitignore.orig and .gitignore.rej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the node_modules folder should be ignored as the github repo for Laravel has it listed in the .gitignore.  Most of that should be added by npm anyways.

[You can view it here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore)

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. I worried that the node_modules folder might be needed in the app itself.